# c# if or statement to specify subject

Tags: c#

I am trying to code an `if` OR statement with an `else if` to follow up to change an email subject header depending on the RAG (Red Amber Green) status of application checks.

The `if` statement checks for the condition of a groupbox `BackColor`. At the moment the statement only returns Green unless all applications are amber and the subject changes to amber or the same for red.

I am looking for one failure to then change the subject.

The code I have put together is below:

```
if ((App1.BackColor == Color.Green) | (App2.BackColor == Color.Green) | (App3.BackColor == Color.Green) | (App4.BackColor == Color.Green))
{
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status GREEN " + Date;
}

else if ((App1.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App2.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App3.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App4.BackColor == Color.Orange))
{
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status AMBER " + Date;
}

else if ((App1.BackColor == Color.Red) | (App2.BackColor == Color.Red) |  (App3.BackColor == Color.Red) | (App4.BackColor == Color.Red))
{
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status Red " + Date;
}
```

I am fairly new to coding in C# using Visual Studio and up to now have found an answer for most things I have had an issue with, but this one I have search both here and on other sites. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `||`, not `|`.

Comment: @rightfold That would not change the result at all since none of the conditions (presumably) have side-effects.

Comment: I'd still use `||` out of habit, but looking at MSDN's docs on `|`, it is still treated as logical OR because the operands are booleans. Granted, "habit" doesn't sound like a good reason to stick with something either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IF` block you have will stop at setting the day status GREEN if *any* of those colors are green.  Ergo, it will only go into the orange section if *none* of the items are green and at least one is orange.  It will only go into the red section if all are red.

SO

If you want it to fall through the other way, meaning that if ANY are red then emit red you need to do one of two things.  Either reverse the if statements such that the red ones are at the top OR get rid of the `ELSE` part and leave them as 3 distinct `IF` statements.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the help with this and both answers worked exactly as I needed. I went with removing the else statements and keeping it as 3 separate If statements.

THanks again

Answer (score 4):

I would reverse the logic so that you check if any of them are RED, then check if any of them are AMBER, and finally if there are no reds or ambers it must be green (depends on your situation of course).

```
// If any of them are red, then code red
if ((App1.BackColor == Color.Red) | (App2.BackColor == Color.Red) |  (App3.BackColor == Color.Red) | (App4.BackColor == Color.Red))
{
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status Red " + Date;
}
// Otherwise, check if any are amber
else if ((App1.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App2.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App3.BackColor == Color.Orange) | (App4.BackColor == Color.Orange))
{
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status AMBER " + Date;
}
// Everything's fine so we give it a green
else
    oMailItem.Subject = "Application Start Of Day Status GREEN " + Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not completely clear with what you want your code to do.  If you want everything green unless one is amber, and amber unless one is red, you need to clearly say so.

If any of the app backcolors are green, then your "subject green" is run and the entire loop terminates.  If you want the amber or red condition to change the subject from green to their color, take out the else statements, giving your three separate if statements.  That way your will get green, then amber if one is amber, then red if one is red.